# Derivation of Feasible Generalized Least Squares Process (Wooldridge 2013)

Tags: regression, least-squares, weighted-least-squares

I'm using Wooldridge's *Introductory Econometrics* (2013) and having some trouble understanding his derivation of the feasible generalized least squares (FGLS) method. He writes, assume that the variance of the error term is given by

$$\mathrm{Var}(u|x) = \sigma^2\exp(\delta_0 + \delta_1x_1 + ... + \delta_kx_k)$$

To transform this into a model that can be estimated using OLS, we rewrite it as

$$u^2 = \sigma^2\exp(\delta_0 + \delta_1x_1 + ... + \delta_kx_k)v$$

where $v$ has a mean equal to unity, conditional on $x = (x_1, ..., x_k)$ If we assume that $v$ is actually independent of $x$, we can write

$$\log(u^2) = a_0 + \delta_1x_1 + ... + \delta_kx_k + e$$

I think I understand that

$$\mathrm{Var}(u|x) = \mathbb{E}[u^2|x] - [\mathbb{E}[u|x]]^2 = \mathbb{E}[u^2|x]$$

and therefore

$$\mathbb{E}[u^2|x] = \sigma^2\exp(\delta_0 + \delta_1x_1 + ... + \delta_kx_k)$$

but how does the expected $\mathbb{E}[u^2|x]$ become $u^2$, and where does the $v$ come from? Additionally, I understand how

$$u^2 = \sigma^2\exp(\delta_0 + \delta_1x_1 + ... + \delta_kx_k) \implies \log(u^2) = a_0 + \delta_1x_1 + ... + \delta_kx_k + e$$

but what happens to the $v$?